# how to add mysql driver package in apache superset when installing using dockers?

Tags: mysql, docker, port, apache-superset

MYSQL is a local instance(3306 = port number)
superset is installed using dockers

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset.git
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, MySQL driver installed on the apache-superset container. If you have to add a specific version you can follow the below method.

```
cd incubator-superset
touch ./docker/requirements-local.txt
echo "mysqlclient==1.4.6" >> ./docker/requirements-local.txt
docker-compose up -d
```